# Open Graph Beta: Add Data to Profile URL

Tags: oauth, dialog, facebook-timeline, open-graph-beta

In the new Open Graph Beta Auth Dialog does the "Add Data to Profile URL" essentially serve as the callback URL where Facebook will send the user after they click the "Add to My Timeline" button?

In a related question, will clicking the "Add to My Timeline" button in the new auth process in itself generate posting an item to the new Timeline page for the user?

Since these new features are in beta, we're not sure what to expect.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/beta/authentication/#add-data

If configured, Reports and stories on Timeline will have a menu option that lets the friends of your app's users click "add to my timeline" to install your app.  Note that the screenshots in the docs are somewhat out of date and should say "Add to Timeline".

Answer (score 1):

When a user clicks on "Add To My Timeline", whenever your app post an Open Graph Action for the user (e.g. Bill listened to Nirvana), it will add it to the timeline if you have Aggregation for that action (e.g. Music I Listen To).